# Resizing NTFS partition by altering total sectors in boot record

Tags: ntfs, mft

I am trying to create an easy way of deploying empty virtual disks by expanding a NTFS formatted 5MB image into whatever size I need. I've been studying the NTFS structure for a while now ([from here](http://www.cse.scu.edu/~tschwarz/coen252_07Fall/Lectures/NTFS.html)), and the MFT is a bit too much for me to dig into right now. I've mananged to create the Boot Record, and it gets correctly identified by the "file" command on Linux.

I am mounting these images using OSFMount on Windows, so they appear as local disks. I've discovered that when changing the total number of sectors to a higher number (taking into account the bytes per sector, etc), the image is usually recognized as properly formatted by Windows. For example, when increasing the sectors count to go from 4 MB to 120 MB, everything works fine. When going from 512 to 520-530, same. However, when going from 4 MB to 130 MB, Windows says the drive is not formatted and proceeds to do so. I've seen a copy of the BootRecord at the end of the disk image too, so I'm editing that as well. I'm not touching anything else.

If the MFT and MFTMirr stay in the same place, but only the total number of sectors is changed, why would Windows complain that the drive is not properly formatted (not finding the MFT I assume?)

Here's the sample image: https://www102.zippyshare.com/v/YfuaIh7X/file.html

Comment: If you have Linux available, don't you also have `ntfsresize` available? It's a known-working tool and you can compare its resized image with your resized image. It also seems like that would be a _much easier_ way of deploying empty virtual disk. (I mean, aside from Windows being capable of doing that on its own already.)

Comment: Indeed it would much, much easier with ntfsresize. However, I took the opportunity to do it in plain Java to learn more about NTFS. I seem to have forgot to mention, I'll do that now. The use case I have for this thing involves pretty much only Java, and I try to stay away from platform-dependent tools like ntfsresize unless it's the only way